# Puppet: Class Ordering / Containment - always wrong order

Tags: puppet

I read a lot about ordering puppet classes with containment (iam using Puppet 6). But it still does not work for me in one case. Maybe my english is not good enough and i miss something. Maybe somebody know what iam doing wrong.

I have a profile to installing a puppetserver (`profile::puppetserver`). This profile has three sub-classes which I *contain* within the `profile::puppetserver`

```rb
class profile::puppetserver(
) {
  contain profile::puppetserver::install
  contain profile::puppetserver::config
  contain profile::puppetserver::firewall
}
```

That works fine for me. Now I want to expand this profile and install `PuppetDB`. For this, i use the `puppetdb` module from [puppet forge](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb):

So what i do is add `profile::puppetserver::puppetdb` and the contain to the `profile::puppetserver`

```rb
class profile::puppetserver::puppetdb(
) {

  # Configure puppetdb and its underlying database
  class { 'puppetdb': }

  # Configure the Puppet master to use puppetdb
  class { 'puppetdb::master::config': }
}
```

1. When i provision my `puppetserver` first and add the `profile::puppetserver::puppetdb` after it, `puppetdb` installs and everything works fine.
2. If I add it directly with `contain`, and provisioning everything at once, it crashes. It's because the `puppetdb` module is installed randomly during my *master server* installs (and also the `postgresql` server and so on). That ends in my `puppetserver` is not running and my `puppetdb` generate no local `ssl` certificates and the service doesn't comes up.

What i try first:

I installed the `puppetdb` Package in my `profile::puppetserver::puppetdb` directly and use the required flag. It works when i provision all at once.

```rb
class profile::puppetserver::puppetdb (
) {

  Package { 'puppetdb':
    ensure => installed,
    require => Class['profile::puppetserver::config']
  }
}
```

So i think i could do the same in the code above:

```rb
class profile::puppetserver::puppetdb(
) {

  # Configure puppetdb and its underlying database
  class { 'puppetdb': 
    require => Class['profile::puppetserver::config']
  }

  # Configure the Puppet master to use puppetdb
  class { 'puppetdb::master::config': 
    require => Class['profile::puppetserver::config']
  }
}
```

But this does not work...

So i read about puppet class containment and ordering by chains. So i did this in my `profile::puppetserver`

```rb
class profile::puppetserver(
) {
  contain profile::puppetserver::install
  contain profile::puppetserver::config
  contain profile::puppetserver::firewall
  contain profile::puppetserver::puppetdb

  Class['profile::puppetserver::install'] ->
  Class['profile::puppetserver::config'] ->
  Class['profile::puppetserver::firewall'] ->
  Class['profile::puppetserver::puppetdb']
}
```

But it still does not have any effect... he still starts to install `postgresql` and the `puppetdb` package during my "puppetserver provisioning" in the install, config, firewall steps.

How i must write the ordering, that all things from the `puppetdb` module, which i call in `profile::puppetserver::puppetdb`, only starts when the rest of the provisioning steps are finished?

I really don't understand it. I think maybe it haves something to do with the fact, that i declare classes from the `puppetdb` module inside of `profile::puppetserver::puppetdb` and not the directly `Resource Type`. Because when i use the `Package Resource Type` with the Require Flag, it seems to work. But i really don't know how to handle this. I think there must be a way or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think maybe it haves something to do with the fact, that i declare
>   classes from the puppetdb module inside of
>   profile::puppetserver::puppetdb and not the directly Resource Type.
>   Because when i use the Package Resource Type with the Require Flag, it
>   seems to work.

Exactly so.

Resources are ordered with the class or defined-type instance that directly declares them, as well as according to ordering parameters and instructions applying to them directly.

Because classes can be declared multiple times, in different places, ordering is more complicated for them.  Resource-like class declarations such as you demonstrate (and which you really ought to avoid as much as possible) do not imply any particular ordering of the declared class.  Neither do declarations via the `include` function.

Class declarations via the `require` function place a single-ended ordering constraint on the declared class relative to the declaring class or defined type, and declarations via the `contain` function place a double-ended ordering constraint similar to that applying to all resource declarations.  The chaining arrows and ordering metaparameters can place additional ordering constraints on classes.

> But i really dont know how to handle this. I think there must be a way or?

Your last example shows a viable way to enforce ordering at the level of `profile::puppetserver`, but its effectiveness is contingent on each of its `contain`ed classes taking the same approach for any classes they themselves declare, at least where those third-level classes must be constrained by the order of the second-level classes.  This appears to be where you are falling down.

Note also that although there is definitely a need to order some things relative to some others, it is not necessary or much useful to try to enforce an explicit total order over all resources.  Work with the lightest hand possible, placing only those ordering constraints that serve a good purpose.